# xText parser usage during runtime configuration

Tags: parsing, plugins, eclipse-plugin, runtime, xtext

I want to use the runtime configuration for running an xText parser. In an example xText project I get the standalone and the runtime configuration for using the parser.

Please can somebody indicate the steps needed to use the parser during runtime in another Eclipse plug-in project. I have no experience with the plugin.xml file and I know I need to create there some extension points.

The xText sample project contain also an ui project which uses the obtained parser during runtime. Still I was not able to understand what things I need from that configuration an what not.

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what your exact problem is. some more hints would be helpflul. maybe a look at http://koehnlein.blogspot.de/2012/11/xtext-tip-how-do-i-get-guice-injector.html or http://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/xtext-calling-the-generator-from-a-context-menu/ can give you some more hints

Comment: Dear Mr. Dietrich, still I am not able to configure things so that I can parse some InputStream. It is in this line:    resource.load(in, resourceSet.getLoadOptions()); Help is highly appreciated.My code breacks here:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource$IOWrappedException: Content is not allowed in prolog.atorg.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:195)
atorg.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:253)atorg.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1518)at smtcodan.parser.MyXtextParser.parse(MyXtextParser.j

Comment: this looks like your config is still wrong. please double check that the file extension is correct and the yourdsl.ui plugin is active.